# Which language is best to study phonetics?

Tags: phonetics

I want to know about languages that make use of most number of phonemes and make use of most of the phonetic principles.

Comment: There is no best language to study phonetics!

Comment: I am new to the field of linguistics. I was wondering if there is any particular language with which phonetics can be studied well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get a list of languages and sounds from UPSID, which has a web interface [here](http://web.phonetik.uni-frankfurt.de/upsid.html). However, it is best to select a language with a number of speakers available to you. !Xoon may be nice and exotic, but it is not trivial to find speakers of the language. You need to have a reasonable number of speakers providing data, so that you have a basis for claiming that what you've found is a property of the language and not just a quirk of the individual speaker.

You also should decide why you are doing this, and what kind of information you need going into the study. One reason to study Icelandic or Finnish is that the phonetics and especially phonology of those languages has been reasonably well worked out, which is not quite the case with Ket, Oromo or Somali. If your goal is to develop a Somali speech-recognition package, you would have to undertake a lot of primary descriptive research on the language in order to be able to know what phonetic data to get. Similarly, there probably would not be enough consumer demand for a Mazateco synthesizer to justify the cost. On the other hand, if you're just interested in an academic study, Mazateco would be a fine language to study.

There's also a potential tradeoff between number of phonemes and degree of contextual variation. When a language has relatively few phonemes, it is communicatively less important to produce a sound in one specific way as opposed to something similar, so a languages with fewer phonemes may have more phonetic processes leading to allophonic variation.

[EDIT]

A concrete example is Hindi. There are plenty of speakers, and there is also a decent amount of phonological and phonetic literature so that you wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel, axle, and saw. I use Google translate synthesis as a crude metric of the state of the art in phonetic NLP for a language, and Hindi seems to be in good shape. Tamil, on the other hand, is in quite sad shape by that metric, and the remaining languages of India are in no shape at all. The state of the art in phonological and phonetic description for Tamil is, at the same time, significantly below that for Hindi. Overall, the best approach, when one is first learning how to do programming on languages, is to pick a language that you know reasonably well. This allows you to catch errors much quicker, when you have some ability to judge that an output is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I agree with you about "...having reasonable number of speakers providing data...". Being new to the field of linguistics, I was wondering if there is any particular (preferably popular) language with which phonetics can be studied well. My short term goal is to explore linguistic and then check out NLP using my programming knowledge. Your discussion was definitely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some information about phoneme inventories (separated by consonants and vowels) in the [WALS survey](http://wals.info/chapter). WALS has also surveys about some phoneme features, e.g., presence of unusual consonants in Chapter 19.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you start with your native language. Once you are familiar with such rules you can then apply them to other languages easily